# Graphviz: Force / leapfrog "column" for box

Tags: graphviz

I would like to recreate the petroleum product tree with graphviz.

[prototype](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-G0JScTGC7m4/UvIGFAx6H1I/AAAAAAAADcM/1AcDPxY-8xo/s1600/petroleum+flow+chart.jpg)

For this I'm glad with graphviz possibility to create a graph structured in columns.

[image: My graph]

But how can I force a box to be rendered in the 3rd instead of the 2nd column without using an empty box as bypass?

Comment: Please upload the first picture to `imgur` as we cannot see this one properly (and don't want to click on unknown links), also show the code to generate the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a small experiment, important part is `rank=same`:

```
digraph g {

rankdir=LR

node [shape=box ]
Petroleum
{rank=same Benzene;Xylene;Butanes}
{rank=same Ethylbenzene;Cyclobenzene;Cumene;"p-Xylene";Toluene}

Petroleum -> Benzene
Petroleum -> Xylene
Petroleum -> Butanes
Petroleum -> Toluene
Benzene -> Ethylbenzene
Benzene -> Cyclobenzene
Benzene -> Cumene
Xylene -> "p-Xylene"

}
```